# Why is iSCSI Trying to Connect on IPv6 at boot?

Tags: iscsi

18.04.02

I recently added an iSCSI target (Synology Diskstation). It mounts just fine at each boot; however, many times, boot time hangs and the only thing I really see that may be causing it is many errors that look like the following:

```
cannot make a connection to fe80::211:32ff:fe1e:66fc:3260 (-1,22)
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening. I disabled ipv6 by doing the following:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Running

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

Returns 1, so I know it is disabled and persists through boot.

I have searched for a couple of days andD all I can come up with is a bug report from like 10 years ago so surely that can't be the reason, could it? Any other ideas are appreciated. Normally, I would just ignore it, but I am not sure that it isn't what is causing the hang.

Answer (score 3):

I finally was able to figure out the problem. Even though I had IPv6 turned off on my box, even after I removed all targets, I noticed that when I re-discovered, it was still pulling both the IPv4 and IPv6 connection from the Synology Diskstation NAS.

I checked settings in the Synology and lo and behold it had its IPv6 turned on. I statically assigned IPv4, but didn't even look at IPv6.

Removed everything on my box again and re-discovered. STILL had both IPv4 and IPv6. After digging deeper into the Synology NAS, there is a setting in the ISCSI Manager -->Target-->Network Bindings that is checked for 'All Network Interfaces'. Not sure why it would still announce it's IPv6 since I disabled it in the network settings, but I specified that it only announce on its IPv4 interface.

One more time, I re-discovered and FINALLY, it was only seeing IPv4 target, which has seemed to have solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to share this. The only post I found - after hours of searching - that resolved my issue.